# Querying from 1 table on multiple conditions without generating multiple lines

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, conditional-statements

The database I'm working with (I have no ability to update or modify anything in it, I'm only supposed to query it for reports I'm creating) is set up in a rather odd way. Sometimes information needs a million intermediary tables to get to it, and other times everything is in the same table.

To get the unique Address that I need, I have to join 3 tables (table that contains invoice info to table that contains the key that assigns a number to each organization to the table that contains all organizations in the database). The last of the three tables has every single company, but companies can have the same of different roles (eg one company can be a supplier, one can be a customer, one can be a partner, etc.), so the table has a "Type" column that says the role where 1=supplier, 2=customer, etc.

The sample code and data are below (sorry, I can't seem to get tables to format properly here):

```
select * from a
join b on a.id=b.id
join c on b.orgid=c.orgid
```

Data:

```
a.OrderID    b.Organization    c.Role
-----------------------------------------    
   123       Acme Inc.            1
   123       Roadrunner Inc.      2
   123       Venture Co.          2
```

The query I'm making needs to pull the order ID, supplier, customer and partner, but no matter how I join it or how I try to use a `WITH` statement, it generates 3 lines where in each line, one of the three roles is named and the rest are NULL.

Would anyone be able to help?

Thanks very much for taking the time to read this long-winded question.

Comment: It sounds like you have duplicate records in the roles database, with companies having NULL for role.  Either that, or your query is really using left/right outer joins.  Can you check these things?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it

Comment: +1 To the request for table structure and sample code. Also, I'd like to point out that the problem you're facing is quite common and not "odd". Having three tables simply means that the DB was designed to handle many-to-many relationships (although I find it odd that an order can belong to more than one customer). Joining two information tables through a relationship mapping table is something you'll find frequently, if you work with (almost) any database.

Comment: need a little more info on how the tables are joined. can you give us the relevant table schemata?

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you closer to your desired result

```
;with cteOrgRoles as
(
select b.id, b.orgid, organization, role
from b 
    inner join c on b.orgid = c.orgid
)
    select 
        a.*,
        r1.organization as role1,
        r2.organization as role2
    from a
        left join cteOrgRoles r1 on a.id = r1.id and r1.role=1
        left join cteOrgRoles r2 on a.id = r2.id and r2.role=2
```

You will get duplicates in the various role columns if you have multiple entries in the other roles